# VBA confused with same named ranges in different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have many workbooks (monthly home accounts) that have the same named ranges. I use a function to perform sumif

`Debit = Application.SumIf(.Range(Codename), Cellpos, .Range(Drname))`

where Codename is a named range of code letters, Cellpos is the specific codeletter I want to sum and the range to sum over is Drname. This works *fine* when only one workbook is open at a time, but when two or more are open the function appears to get confused which workbook I am referring to - all hell breaks out! How can I be more specific? I can use the workbook name & worksheet name if I could only figure the syntax! The Full Function is this

````
Function Diff02(Codename As String, Drname As String, Crname As String, Shtname As String, Cellpos As String) As Single
           
    Worksheets(Shtname).Activate
    
    With Sheets(Shtname)
               
        Debit = Application.SumIf(.Range(Codename), Cellpos, .Range(Drname))
        Credit = Application.SumIf(.Range(Codename), Cellpos, .Range(Crname))
        
        Diff02 = Debit - Credit
    End With
End Function
    ```
````

Comment: You need to properly reference the workbook and sheet then so `dim w as excel.workbook:set w=workbooks("xyz"):w.sheets("abc").range......`

Comment: As you are using `.Range` (with a leading dot), you must have a `With`-statement someone. Would be helpfull if you would show it.

Comment: If you are specific enough and always specify the workbook for **all** `Range` objects, than VBA does not guess. Make sure you use something like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(…)` or `Workbooks("WbName.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(…)`. Only precise code gives precise results.

Comment: Thanks for all your input, I fully realise VBA is smart and I am just learning!

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
With Sheets(Shtname)
```

you need to specify in which workbook `Sheets(Shtname)` is. For example

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Shtname)
```

or

```
With Workbooks("WbName.xlsm").Worksheets(Shtname)
```

---

Remove `Worksheets(Shtname).Activate`. Selecting and activating is only needed in rare cases. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).